# freebsd: current dir of running process by process id

Tags: process, freebsd, working-directory

I have the pid of a running process in freebsd.
How do I obtain its current directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the inode number of the current working directory with

```
fstat -p $PID
```

It looks like lsof will give you a human readable form of the current working directory, but we don't have that installed on any of the local FreeBSD machines, so I can't verify that.

Answer (score 3):

fstat can find the inode number and filesystem, and find can find the correct directory.

Try this:

```
fstat -p $$|perl -ane '$F[3] eq "wd" && system("find",$F[4],"-xdev","-inum",$F[5],"-print");'
```

When run as non-root, find will probably output quite a few "Permission denied" messages which can be avoided by inserting `close(STDERR);`
in front of the `$F[3]` (after the first single quote).

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions of FreeBSD, you can use `procstat -f $PID`, which shows the pathname if it is still in the kernel name cache.

Answer (score -1):

/proc/$PID/cwd contains a symlink to the programmes current working directory.

Comment: It should be noted that the `/proc` filesystem is not necessarily available in all installations of FreeBSD.

Comment: This works for Linux, but doesn't seem to be part of /proc in FreeBSD.  See the procfs man page at: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procfs